# React: Simple way to detect if a component is inside a table

Tags: reactjs, html-table, components, react-props

I know that I could use Context or props, but I want to see if there is something more generic or simpler to detect if I have my component standalone (let's say directly in a form) or if I have it inside a table.

In React JS.

Answer (score 1):

In order to check if your current element is a descendant of some other element you can walk up the DOM starting with the element in question with `Node.parentElement()` ([docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/parentElement)) and check whether that element has the attributes you're looking for (e.g in your case nodeName `TABLE` ([docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeName))).

In order to get a handle on your react element, you can use a `ref` ([docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html))